# How can I set up a "remote pair-coding" environment linux to linux?

Tags: ssh, development-environment, pair-programming

I did some research on how to enable a pair-coding environment remotely so someone else on their MacOx/Linux box could view my screen (I code using vim + the rails plugin).

I read Evan Light's blog on his set up here, but I don't have an open source router:

http://evan.tiggerpalace.com/articles/2011/10/17/some-people-call-me-the-remote-pairing-guy-/

So the SSH is tricky since I don't have a sticky IP.

What is an easy way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So the SSH is tricky since I don't have a sticky IP.

There's a bunch of tools to get you a DNS name to point towards a dynamic IP (some of them are even free). I've used [No-IP.com](http://www.no-ip.com/), but not for several years (and have no affiliation). You don't necessarily need to have an open-source router - you can run the daemon on your computer, and then use port-forwarding to get incoming SSH connections to your computer.

You should take this over to [SuperUser.com](http://superuser.com) - it's probably more on-topic there.

Comment: If I use No-IP do I just create a user?  I feel like I've tried that process and get stuck...maybe No-IP solves the dynamic IP aspect....we had some kind of a security error so hoping for some step-by-step guide (or even better, a canned solution)?  I'll try to migrate this to SU.com

Comment: This didn't give me the complete answer, but the basic structure and No-IP.com is useful...so awarding the answer to get closure...thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not for pair-programming so far, but I usually do my screen-sharing through [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/index.aspx). It is extremely easy to set up, and passes through routers like hot knife through butter. However, it transfers the GUI, so it can be somewhat slow (depending on your connection).

Comment: ouch, that's my fear that it may be slow...it feels like those kinds of viewers are super-slow.....but I don't know, I haven't tried specifically Team Viewer...my hope was that it could be tmux or something since I am in the console.....thought?